# PHPMailer in Joomla Model Error 500 when there is keyword "use"

Tags: joomla, model, namespaces, phpmailer, http-status-code-500

I am trying to send mail using phpmailer from joomla model, here is code

```
require '/opt/cdf/ThemeComponent/models/vendor/autoload.php';
            require("/opt/cdf/ThemeComponent/models/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");
            require("/opt/cdf/ThemeComponent/models/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
            require("/opt/cdf/ThemeComponent/models/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");

            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

            $email = new PHPMailer();
            $email->IsSMTP();
            $email->SMTPSecure = false;
            $email->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
            $email->Host = "stage1.dmz.gr";
            $email->Mailer = "smtp";
            $email->Port = 25;
            $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $email->Encoding = 'base64';
            $email->IsHTML(true);
            $email->SetFrom("noreply@mydomain.com");
            $email->Subject = "ok";
            $email->Body = "<b>asdf</b>";
            $email->AddAddress("wasimxe@gmail.com");
            $email->Send();
```

This code is working fine out of joomla directory but when I use it in joomla model, it throw http error no. 500 and if i commend line `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` then error gone but mail doesn't sent.

Answer (score 0):

The `use` statement is for importing namespaced classes into your current namespace, and you can [read the docs on it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). It was introduced in PHP 5.3, so this error suggests you are running PHP 5.2 or older, which is a **very, very bad idea** as it has not received security patches for [over 8 years](https://www.php.net/eol.php). Your server is vulnerable to many known attacks, so you should upgrade **immediately**.

Comment: On the same server, same code is working out of Joomla directory. It's PHP 5.6

Comment: Why are you loading the classes manually when you are already loading an autoloader that should do it for you?

Comment: OK, that's curious - I suggest looking in your error logs which should say why it is crashing.